# Magento 2 - wrong number of digits between separators for prices in Indian Rupees

Tags: internationalization, magento2, magento2.2

I am using Magento 2.2.3. my default currency is INR, but it shows in the wrong format:

[image]

But it should be ₹77,65,000.00. How do we correct price format? Currently its wrong... like USD.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the currency format by following code.

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of Object Manager
    $priceHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data'); // Instance of Pricing Helper
    $price =  1000; //Your Price
    $formattedPrice = $priceHelper->currency($price, true, false);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. File path: vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml
2. On line number 3353, under section currencyFormat and type = "standard", change the pattern from  `<pattern>¤#,##0.00</pattern>` to `<pattern>¤ #,##,##0.00</pattern>`
3. Still, on PDP page and cart page summary the price format does not change because the prize format is coming from the JS in which Magento using a RegExp function for only US price format.
   For that, please change the code in the below file.

   File path: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-utils.js` (First extend this file in your theme directory and do the respected changes)

   Under the function formatPrice below this line comment all the line in the respective function.

   ```
   i = parseInt(
       amount = Number(Math.round(Math.abs(+amount || 0) + 'e+' + precision) + ('e-' + precision)),
       10
   ) + '';
   ```

   And add this set of code below the above line.

   ```
   var x=i;
   x=x.toString();
   var afterPoint = '';
   if(x.indexOf('.') > 0)
       afterPoint = x.substring(x.indexOf('.'),x.length);
   x = Math.floor(x);
   x=x.toString();
   var lastThree = x.substring(x.length-3);
   var otherNumbers = x.substring(0,x.length-3);
   if(otherNumbers != '')
       lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
   var response = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree + afterPoint;
   return pattern.replace('%s', response);
   ```
4. deploy and `rm -rf var/cache/*

And then you're done. For Example: A price previously displayed like `453,453`, will now display in the Indian manner like `4,53,453`.

Comment: I suggest you to do not change the core files of the magento, create your module add en.xml file.